# How to disable label in the Pie chart using Extjs

Tags: extjs, pie-chart

I would like to disable label from Extjs pie chart.

If anyone has an example that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What label? Can you provide a screenshot or any hint?

Comment: There can be multiple labels in pie chart. You have to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

assuming that we are talking about `Ext.chart.series.Pie`, which inherits from `Ext.chart.series.Series`; the 4.x documentation for `onCreateLabel(storeItem, item, i, display)` states, that when `display` is set to `false`, the label will be not be displayed.

the [5.x documentation](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.4/api/Ext.chart.label.Label.html#cfg-hidden) for `Ext.chart.label.Label` states, that there is a config `hidden`.

it's difficult to provide any code, while not even knowing which framework version it is. this question's op should provide more details and/or a [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com), in order to allow proper answers. embedding ExtJS 5/6 GPL in a "code snippet" did not work out... however, here's a configuration which hides all the labels:

```
series: [{
    type: 'pie',
    label: {
        display: false
    }
}]
```